# ajax codeigniter table crud

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i use codeigniter 3 and need some tips help i get error on parse database ajax
want to list all food which contain this recipes // add more food ... delete food

```
 {
    $list = $this->person->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $person) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $person->reteta;
        $row[] = $person->calorii;
        $row[] = $person->proteine;
        $row[] = $person->lipide;
        $row[] = $person->carbohidrati;
        $row[] = $person->fibre;


        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$person->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void()" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$person->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->person->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->person->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
```

Comment: "* i get error on parse database*": which error do you get?

Comment: explain your problem what error you get, explain your question a bit more. So we can understand and help.

Comment: http://craftwow.go.ro/Person/ajax_editmyrecipes check